# Is there a way to create a diagonal dimension in numpy?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the most efficient way to create a NumPy array `res` of shape (M, N, N) from an input array `ar` of shape (M, N) such that `res[m][n][n] = ar[m][n]` for all m and n, and `res[m][n][p] = 0` for all n != p?

Answer (score 1):

use broadcasting and advanced indexing. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np

M, N = ar.shape
res = np.zeros((M, N, N))

# Assign the values from ar to the diagonal of res
res[np.arange(M)[:, None], np.arange(N), np.arange(N)] = ar

print(res)
```